# Oyster - buying travelcard after journey on same day

Tags: london, fares, oyster-card

I remember catching the night bus home in the early hours one day. Later that day, I bought a 7 day travelcard on my Oyster. On my journey history, it gave me an 'automatic refund' for the bus fare

Is this the case in general? If I make a journey and then buy a travelcard on the same day, will that journey be refunded?

Comment: As it was the same day travelcard, it was refunded because your travelcard became valid from that day 0000 hrs onward.

Comment: Yes, it's valid "at any time" on the day of purchase, until before 4:30 am on the day after expiry. For a Travelcard with a 4 November start date, it shows an expiry date of 10 November, and it is valid from 00:00 on 4 November, to 04:30 on 11 November.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the people who commented.

Yes, I can confirm that all journeys made on the day that the travelcard is valid for are eligible for refunds.

However, I recently made a bus and a Tube journey, and bought a 7 travelcard later. But the two fares were not refunded. I used the contact form [available here on the TfL website](https://tfl.gov.uk/help-and-contact/) to ask why I had been charged. They confirmed that I should have been refunded, and said it would take place next time I complete a journey on the Tube (i.e., touch in and touch out). It did indeed work, now I can move on with my life. *Or can I?*

**Update**

This has happened a second time. I contacted them again, but received no response so contacted them again. I had a response to the 2nd of these enquiries, offering me a refund, as before. I later got a response to the 1st of these enquiries, from a different customer services adviser, saying I am not entitled to a refund!

So I checked the [TfL Conditions of Carriage](http://content.tfl.gov.uk/tfl-conditions-of-carriage.pdf), which, on page 31, does say a season ticket is valid

> From 0001 on the start date and for any journey that starts before 0430 on the day after the expiry date shown

So it does look like I am eligible for a refund. But my advice is, **attempt to buy a travelcard before you make a journey**.